# Can I define custom CSS/QSS properties for my custom Qt UI elements?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtstylesheets

For example, I have a GraphWidget, which renders graph. Currently, I use getters and setters to set graph properties such as:

- background color
- line color
- marker font size and color

It would be much more convenient to use CSS for that:

```
GraphWidget {
    line-color: red;
    line-width: 2px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

The problem is that I do not know how to obtain the CSS properties assigned to the widget. And I would also prefer to properly **inherit** properties such as `background` or `color` (for marker's text color).

Is there any API for extending the CSS styles in Qt 5?

Comment: Mind explaining the downvote? I think I phrased the question clear and well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using QCssParser for parsing css file for custom widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833577/using-qcssparser-for-parsing-css-file-for-custom-widget)

Comment: @IMAN4K you must be kidding me :D You asked and self answered a question after I asked this one, then you want to close this, older, question as duplicate of your self answered one?

Comment: Actually i saw your question recently and my question (+ answer) is more general.however it's on you:)

Comment: @IMAN4K If your solution turns to be working, I'll gladly link&upvote. But you should at least describe solution, not just link to files (I think this applies generally to answers on SO).

Answer (score 0):

There's no API but you could access the style sheet of the widgets using QWidget::styleSheet, and parse it yourself

Comment: That doesn't really solve the problem - I would have to parse that for all parent widgets as well.

Comment: so write a parser that can be applied recursively

Comment: Well you don't say... but if there's no API for this, it's not worth the effort.